# Proper way to create and mange jdbc connections in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc

I am building a spark application in java which will fetch records from multiple tables and store them in a spark dataset and then will manipulate and update those records several times in DB.

Currently I have created a broadcast map which holds the database properties(url,user,pass etc) and in each method I create a new connection using which I run my sql queries in jdbc. Note that this is happening in many methods in different classes.

I need an efficient way to manage jdbc connection so that it does not create multiple connections and thus affects the performance on production database. Is there a way to initialize a Hikari pool once and send it across all executers/worker nodes? Or any other efficient way is welcomed.

Comment: A good question, I have never seen any case where people are creating connection pooling when using spark. The connection pool is easy to create in any java application and any library can be used, however, making it available over different JVM during runtime (similar to your data broadcast to avoid network calls) might be tricky. I would prefer to load small data at the driver and broadcast them, this will avoid all connection but connection pooling will add value. Connection pooling only saves time to establish the connection which is important (OLTP) use cases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. 
I got your suggestion but thing is that the application is using the spark map methods in multiple places inside which I have the logic for the jdbc updates. So broadcasting datasets won't be that feasible for me.

What I am thinking is using one connection in each method and run the queries in batch in jdbc. Will that be a bit efficient than the current one ?